# Not able to assign data of a local variable inside Promise to outside variable

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I am building an array inside promise but I want the array to be used outside globally. My code:

```
AllDropdownValues: any[];

async filterAllComponent(inputdata) {
     let a=[], b=[],c=[];
    a=  await this.getfilterPlaces(inputdata);
    b= this.getfilterTransporter(inputdata);
    c= this.getfilterVehicles(inputdata);
    let getplaceArray = [],
  getTransporterArray = [],
  getVehicleArray = [];
  var AllDropdownValueslocal:any[];

let getPlacePromise = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getplaceArray = a;
    resolve("got places\n");
  });
};

let getTransporterPromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getTransporterArray =  b;
    resolve(message + "got Transporter");

  });
};

let getVehiclePromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getVehicleArray = c;
    resolve(message + "got vehicle");

  });
};

getPlacePromise().then(function (result) {
  return getTransporterPromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  return getVehiclePromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  AllDropdownValueslocal = getTransporterArray.concat(getVehicleArray).concat(getplaceArray);

}).catch(function(){
  console.log("error");
});
this.AllDropdownValues =  AllDropdownValueslocal;
}
```

I am trying to assign the local variable **AllDropdownValueslocal** to a global variable **AllDropdownValue**. when I console log, **AllDropdownValueslocal** is coming ok but **AllDropdownValues** is not coming. How do I get the value of AllDropdownValueslocal outside the scope?

Comment: You have a name conflict with `filterAllComponent`: it's an array and a function (which is missing the keyword function)

Comment: It was my typing mistake. I have edited the question. Have a look

Comment: What's the point of `getPlacePromise`, `getTransporterPromise`, and `getVehiclePromise`? They do nothing but immediately assign values from the local scope to the `a`, `b`, `c` variables in the local scope. Is this your real code?

Comment: @Bergi I need to concatanate all three arrays once I get the value of getfilterPlaces. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: @UDGogs No. All these functions with `new Promise` in your code are totally pointless (unless you tell me what you need them for). Keep the first 4 lines of your `filterAllComponent` method, then `return a.concat(b, c);`. That's it.

Comment: ya right. I couldn't see it through. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can assign it to the global variable, but you cannot use the global variable until the promise is fulfilled. It's pretty pointless to use a separate variable when you have to wait for the promise anyway. Instead, fulfill the promise with the value.

In your code, `AllDropdownValueslocal` is not global, it's local to your `async filterAllComponent` method. Instead of assigning to it from a `then` callback, you should just use `await`.